# Why did sub_match and basic_string comparsion operator implemented with extra copy of string?

Tags: c++, regex, string, templates, overloading

The Standard n4713 says about `operator==` for `basic_string` and `sub_match`:

> ```
> template<class BiIter, class ST, class SA>  
> bool operator==( const basic_string<typename iterator_traits<BiIter>::value_type, ST, SA>& lhs, const sub_match<BiIter>& rhs);
> ```
>
> Returns: rhs.compare(typename
>   sub_match::string_type(lhs.data(), lhs.size())) == 0

So, the whole new string is created from the `basic_string` `lhs` parameter (I think the reason is possibly different allocator types), but the same result could be without an exta copy string:

```
rhs.compare(lhs.data()) == 0
```

We can just call overload for `const value_type*` without any extra copying.
Is this an oversight of the Standard, or am I missed some small detail?

Comment: The standard library is allowed to implement things like this in any way that produces the same result. Can you write a program that can tell whether the library used the code in the specification or used some other code that doesn't copy? (yes, if you provide your own string class that counts copies; no if you don't)

Comment: “We can just call overload for `const value_type*`” — can we?! What happens if the string contains `'\0'`?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, but it must contain '\0', isn't it?

Comment: @user3514538 I’m not talking about the null termination. I’m talking about *embedded* null. E.g. a string of length 5 whose second character is `'\0'`. That’s a valid C++ string, but not representable as a C string.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, hmm, maybe you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the implementation of a function with how the standard says it will behave. They're not the same thing. An implementation can implement this function in any way so long as the return value is identical to what it would have been if it were implemented as described.

Specifically, [the standard states](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/structure.specifications#3.5) about the "Returns" part of a function specification:

> Returns: a description of the value(s) returned by the function

Contrast this with:

> Effects: the actions performed by the function

Returns is descriptive; Effects is prescriptive. Returns describes the value, not how it gets computed. Therefore, the as-if rule can apply: any equivalent code which would compute the same value is valid.

Comment: Not so sure about that.  it says *Returns* not *Effects* or *Equivalent* like it does [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/string.op.append)

Comment: I thought that "Returns:" means a serious requirement about how the return value must be computed. Possibly, some paragraph in the Standard clarifies that

Comment: @NathanOliver: "Returns:" is defined in the standard as "a description of the value(s) returned by the function". In this case, a boolean true/false value is returned. There is no statement that the computation of that value must be done exactly as stated, so the as-if rule applies. Indeed, the phrase "a description" suggests that it is descriptive, not prescriptive.

Comment: But [\[structure.specifications\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/structure.specifications) also has *The value returned from F is specified by F's Returns element*, which makes me uncertain. I guess I have a question to ask now :)

Comment: @NathanOliver: That paragraph only applies when an *Effects* statement is present and says that it is "Equivalent to" something.

Comment: Aha.  Cool.  Thanks.  +1